# Questions about solution to the following question: a group $G$ of order $n$ has $2^{n-1}$ subgroups, prove that $G=<e>$ or $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group of order $n$ and $G$ has $2^{n-1}$ subgroups, prove that $G=\langle e\rangle$ or $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$

The solutions from the student solutions manual read as follows:

> There are $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $G$ which contains $e$.  By hypothesis each of these subsets is a subgroup.  If $|G|>2$, let $e,a,b$ be distinct elements.  Apply Corollary 7.27, to show that $a^{2}=e$, since ${e, a}$ is a subgroup and $a=a^{3}a^{-2}=e,$ a contradiction.

My question is, does the solution mean that if we want to consider the situation of a group and forming subgroups by only consider the subsets of power set of the order of the group being $n$ number of elements. Then the only way this is possible is $n=2,$ meaning a group with two elements only?  Actually, I thought the question is not possible with the counter example of the group $S_n$ and that half of its elements of odd permutation can't be consider as a subgroup.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $|G|=n$ and $G$ has $2^{n-1}$ subgroups.

Some subsets of $G$ contain the identity element. There are exactly $2^{n-1}$ of these.

A subgroup, by definition, must conntain. the identity element. So if you want a subgroup, you must select it from the list of subsets that contain the identity element. But you need $2^{n-1}$ different subgroups, and you only have $2^{n-1}$ subsets to choose from. That means that every one of these subsets is a subgroup.

The proof then asks you to suppose that $G$ has at least three different elements: $e$, $a$ and $b$.

Since $\{e,a\}$ is a subset containing $e$, it must be a subgroup. Therefore $a^2=e$.

Since $\{e,a,b\}$ is also a subset containing $e$, it too is a subgroup. Because of what we know about subgroups of order $3$, we have $a^2=b$.
This is a contradiction because $b$ is supposed to be not equal to $e$.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanations.  If is okay, i still like to clarify the following minor point. The result of the exercise means that the result is only true for the case of a group $G$ containing two elements?

Comment: the correct statement is "If $G$ is a group of order $n$ and $G$ has $2^{n-1}$ subgroups, then $n=1$ or $n=2$"

Comment: ah ok ok.  I did not include the n=1 case because it just seem trivial.  Again thank you for clearing it up.   :)